# Have there been any study that document the evidence of the changing ratio of the biomass of different trophic levels?

Tags: ecology

You would expect a number such as the producers (photosynthetic) biomass to consumers + decomposers biomass ratio is a very important indicator for sustainability. It is also very probable that the ratio has been changed due to human activities (land clearance, animal agriculture etc.) which have resulted in the likes of climate change (which is in a sense just a problem of excessive mineralization (both industrial and biological) relative to immobilization by producers). Have there been any studies that try to calculate and monitor this number? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Related: [In a typical model ecosystem, what might the percentage of plants be to top predators and everything inbetween?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27830/in-a-typical-model-ecosystem-what-might-the-percentage-of-plants-be-to-top-pred)

Comment: Related answer to [*References concerning the relative population sizes of predator and prey*](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60627/references-concerning-the-relative-population-sizes-of-predator-and-prey/64279#64279), specifically dealing with biomass scaling of predators and prey.